# Mod rewrite. Without endslash redirect to endslash

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo

For some seo reasons I need to redirect all links like

http://site.com/some/category
to
http://site.com/some/category/

So I've solved this issue with this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

But this rule also catchs links like

http://site.com/some/category/some.file and redirects it to  http://site.com/some/category/some.file/

I have tried something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([^\.]*)!/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another rewrite condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Or you could change your last rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]*[^/\.])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
RewriteRule (.*/[^\.]*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```